# UIViewController released without viewWillDisappear: being called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uidocument

I have a basic implementation of `UITableViewController` that presents a `UIDocument`. A reference to the document is kept as instance variable of the view controller.

In `viewWillDisappear:` I close the document if the view controller is removed (and not a sub-viewcontroller pushed to the stack):

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {    
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (!self.keepDocumentOpenAfterNavigatingAway) {
        [self.deckDocument closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){ 
            // As side effect, this retains 'self' until 
            // the document is closed:
            self.document = nil;
        }];
    }
 }
```

Now, once in a while I receive crash reports caused by this (app is for iOS 7):

```
objc_msgSend() selector name: _setInConflict:
```

I suspect that maybe the view controller was deallocated without `viewWillDisappear:` being called. Then the document would have been deallocated along with it  without being closed. When the conflict comes in from iCloud, the app crashes.

Maybe this happens while the app is in the background and runs low on memory? Is there such a scenario where a view controller would get deallocated without `viewWillDisappear:` being called?

*EDIT:* To clarify, this only happens in production, I was not able to reproduce this myself. That's why I'm assuming it might be related to a low memory/background scenario. I issued low memory warnings in the simulator, without any luck.

Comment: You suspect but you actually did not check

Comment: @Andy Yes, I suspect. That is the point of my question. Is it possible that a UIViewController instance gets deallocated automatically by the system? I'd appreciate if you could remove the down vote.

Comment: First of all you should not rely on `viewWillDisappear` or `viewWillAppear` since these methods can be called more than once in case of interactive transitions. Try using `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` which are more reliable. Second, you have to debug your code, this is a part of development process. You've got downvote from me for unwillingness to debug your code and basically waste time of people trying to help others with real problems/questions.

Comment: @Andy, I spent days trying to reproduce this issue, both, in the simulator and on 2 different devices without any luck. After a few more hours of going through the docs, I'm out of options and decided to post the question here. Please remove the down vote, it is not helping. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe simply `self.keepDocumentOpenAfterNavigatingAway` was set to `YES`? Or closing the document failed for some reason (it seems you ignore `success` parameter in the completion handler)?

Comment: @michalCiuba `self.keepDocumentOpenAfterNavigatingAway` is only set to `YES` if another view controller is pushed to the stack. In this case, my view controller would be the parent view controller. Is there a scenario where iOS would remove/deallocate a parent view controller?